# Unable to use Clipboard in flutter_background_service

Tags: android, flutter, dart, foreground-service

When I run the code by tapping a button, it works fine. However, when I try running it in the **onStart** function of **flutter_background_service**, it stops after printing 'Step 1' without any error messages. Here is the relevant code:

```
try {
  if (ipAddress == null) {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ipAddress = await pref.getString('ip');
  } else if (ipAddress != null) {
    final IO.Socket socket = IO.io("http://$ipAddress:8080", <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });
    print('Step 1');
    final clipData = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
    print('Step 2');
    socket.emit('clipboard', clipData?.text);
  } else {
    print('Failed');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error Occurred: $e');
}
```

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Ensuring proper configuration and startup of the background service.
Testing on a physical device instead of an emulator.

I want to run this in foreground.
Any suggestions or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is that the flutter_background_service plugin does not allow you to run code that requires user interaction in the onStart function. This is because the onStart function is called when the service is started, and the user is not interacting with the application at that time. you can use the onResume function to run the code that requires user interaction.